# CURL isn't sending cookie data from file

Tags: curl, cookies

I'm working on a script that needs to authenticate with a session and I'm trying to use curl to store and retrieve the cookie data.  I can store the data into the cookies.txt file but when I try to retrieve the cookie data it isn't being sent

```
curl -c cookies.txt %AUTHURL%

curl -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -d "webUsername=admin&webPassword=1111" %AUTHURL2% >> %logfile%

curl -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -d "HTTP_Set_Config_Attrib=FALSE" %POSTURL% >> %logfile%
```

The cookies.txt file is created after this

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

192.168.0.12    FALSE   /   TRUE    0   PHPSESSID   4b292d94766690a9fc2539f29109406f
```

However when I wireshark the second line

```
POST /userpost/x.set HTTP/1.1
User  -Agent: curl/7.15.1 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.15.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8a zlib/1.2.3
Host: 192.168.0.12
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 90
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

HTTP_Authenticate_fn&webUsername=admin&webPassword=1111
```

I don't see the cookie value, if I do this in my web browser the wireshark shows

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=b7419746c6e18ffd357a408c95e1ad3a
```

I've tried just about every combination I could think of including explicit paths for the cookies.txt files.

Comment: Seems to have to do with the 'secure'  part of the cookie 192.168.0.12    FALSE   /  *TRUE*.  When I change that to false it starts to send the cookie.  This is weird since my browser must be ignoring the securing setting.